# Why is my verification code marking input wrong even when it's correct?

Tags: python

I am trying to code a game that displays the first letter of a song and the artist and requires the user to guess the song in two tries. However, when I try to verify that the answer is correct (which is always is) it still says it is wrong.

My code is as follows:

```
import random

for x in range(0, 13):
    randNum = int(random.randint(0, 13))

    song = open("Songs.txt", "r")
    songname = str(song.readlines()[randNum])
    print(songname[0])
    song.close()

    artist = open("Artists.txt", "r")
    artistname = artist.readlines()[randNum]
    print(artistname)
    artist.close()

    songGuess = input("What is the song called?")
    for x in range(0,1):
        if songGuess == songname:
            print("Answer correct!")
        else:
            songguess = input("Incorrect! Try again:")
            x = x + 1
        if x == 2:
            print("GAME OVER")
            break

    x = x+1
    if x == 13:
        break 
quiz()
```

What should happen is that the user should have two tries to guess the name of the song when only given the first letter of its name and the artist, and if they cannot guess it by the end of the game, it should end.

Comment: This might not be the error you're looking for, but `(songGuess != '' or songGuess != ' ')` is always true. `songGuess` must be not-equal to at least one of those strings.

Comment: Hi @khelwood ! The code I had before was an old version of something a friend had tested out. I have changed it to the new version and would like to hear your opinions on that as the issue is more relevant to that.

Comment: Hi Neusha, note that `x in range(0,1)` will only returns one value `0`, so your loop will only run once.

Comment: You're using `x` as a variable in two nested `for` loops. I'm pretty sure that's wrong.

Comment: Do a `print("{}".format((songGuess, songname)))` bevor `if songGuess == songname:` to see which values you are comparing.

Answer (score 0):

Try this one. Instead of a for loop, a while loop is used.

Generally, when you have a counter, it's best to use a `while` loop. So, in this case, since you're looking to check for a variable to run a small part of code for a `y` number of times, `while` loop is best.

```
import random

for x in range(0, 13):
    randNum = int(random.randint(0, 13))

    song = open("Songs.txt", "r")
    songname = str(song.readlines()[randNum])
    print(songname[0])
    song.close()

    artist = open("Artists.txt", "r")
    artistname = artist.readlines()[randNum]
    print(artistname)
    artist.close()
    y = 0

    songGuess = input("What is the song called?")
    while(y<=2):
        if songGuess == songname:
            print("Answer correct!")
            break
        else:
            y = y + 1
            songguess = input("Incorrect! Try again:")

        if y == 2:
            print("GAME OVER")
            break


quiz()
```

Answer (score 0):

1. You're trying to use X as counter for the total number of turns as well as the number of guess attempts within a turn. Create a separate variable for the number of turns (such as num_turns in my example).
2. You're modifying the variable x within the loop. I haven't seen very many cases where that's a good idea. The for loop should do all the incrementing for you.
3. As someone else said, a while loop might make more sense here since you're checking for a correct answer *until* you find one or the max guesses is reached
4. You don't need to check for the end of a for loop and break out of it.
5. This isn't really related, but you're reading the files on each iteration. It would be more efficient to load them once into memory and access them from there.

I would rewrite the code as follows, but there are many different variations that would work.

```
import random

# Set these to whatever makes sense for your use case.
max_turns = 5
max_guesses = 2

# Load these from wherever you want. This is just some dumb testing data.
songs = load_songs() # you'll need to write some code to do this
artists = load_artists() # you'll need to write some code to do this

for turn_counter in range(max_turns):

    # Pick a random song:
    randNum = int(random.randint(0, 11))
    song_name = songs[randNum]
    artistname = artists[randNum]

    print()
    print(song_name[0])
    print(artistname)

    # Prompt for a guess:
    song_guess = input("What is the song called?\n> ")

    # Let the user guess until they hit the max tries:
    guess_counter = 0
    correct_guess = False
    while True:
        if song_guess == song_name:
            correct_guess = True
            break

        guess_counter += 1
        if guess_counter>=max_guesses:
            break

        # Song wasn't guessed correctly and we haven't hit 
        # the max guesses yet, so try again:
        song_guess = input("Incorrect! Try again:\n> ")

    # We're out of the while loop, so either the song was guessed
    # correctly, or we hit the max number of guesses. Find out which:
    if correct_guess:
        print("Answer correct!")
    else:
        print("GAME OVER")
        break
```